# Does super keyword in Java class compiles to this.getClass.getSuperClass()...?

Tags: java, inheritance, keyword, extends, super

I am trying to find out the implementation behind `super` keyword in JAVA.

I have created an abstract class and one public class extend

```
abstract class AbsClass {

    private String colour;

    public AbsClass(String colour) {
        this.colour = colour;
    }

    void findColour()
    {
        System.out.println(this.colour);
    }

    //getter and setter 
}
```

Now I have one public class implementing that abstract class.

```
package abstraact.concept;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class ExtendAbsClass extends AbsClass {

    public ExtendAbsClass(String colour) {
        super(colour);
    }


    @Override
    void findColour() {
        super.findColour();

    /* Is the above line similar to

        mthd = this.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredMethod("findColour", null);
        mthd.invoke(this, null); 
    */


    System.out.println("Colour in sub class method " + this.getColour());

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExtendAbsClass absClass = new ExtendAbsClass("Blue");
        absClass.findColour();
    }
}
```

Where I can see the implementation behind the `super` Keyword as well as the 'this` keyword.

How the `super` keyword access the superclass method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In binary code: `invokespecial AbsClass.findColour()`.

Comment: What do you mean by "implementation"? You could always look at the bytecode that the compiler produces for your program...

Answer (score 1):

Even though there are some basic constructs java, that are replaced by a portion of java like String concatenation where

```
"Colour: " + this.getColour()
```

means

```
new StringBuilder(new String(new char[] {'C', 'o'..., ' '}).intern()).append(this.getColour());
```

However, I don't think this applies to any keyword. Neither super, nor this, throws, extends, and so on can be impleted by other java expressions. They build up the base of the language and are not just syntactic sugar to work efficiently with this language. Thus they build by byte codes and other basic constrcts.